# Courses Disappearing in ASP Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm having issues within a site that I recently took over. It is a school site that uses a table where students can reserve seats for classes. The issue I'm running into is that the classes disappear the day of and students think the class is canceled. The customer wants the class to be visible until the day after the class is over. I'm not really sure how tables like this work in ASP.Net. Any help would be great.

[PCC Public Safety](http://www.pccpublicsafety.com/LawEnforcement/CourseListing.aspx)

Comment: Don't think we can help with the little information you gave. Did you have a look a the code? Does the data come from a database? If yes, you should find the query that fetches it. There is probably a WHERE clause on some date field that you should change

Comment: So is this asp-classic, or asp.net? If it's the former, why did you add the latter tag, and vice versa? The two are totally different, you know.

Comment: It's ASP.Net. I must've misclicked the wrong tag and didn't notice.My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to go on, but first thing that comes to mind.

now() <= '1/1/2014'

Actually means *Midnight* on the Jan 1st 2014.  If they have all day to signup, try somthng like:

now() <= '1/1/2014 23:59:59'

That will give them until midnight on the day.